# How can I get pandoc to recognize my custom YAML fields?

Tags: pandoc, yaml

I have a markdown file that starts like this:

```
--- 
title: Some Title
author: 
- family: Barson
  given: Foobius
---
```

And I'd like to get pandoc to extract this information and output it. So I have a simple template that looks like this:

```
title: $title$
author: $author$
author given: $author.given$ 
author family: $author.family$
```

Yet when I run `pandoc my-file.md --template=my-template.html`, I get this:

```
title: Some Title
author: true
author given:  
author family:
```

But what I was expecting to get was be this:

```
title: Some Title
author: Foobius Barson
author given:  Foobius
author family: Barson
```

What am I doing wrong with this pandoc template?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out myself. It turns out I just had to wrap the `$author.given$`s in a `for` loop:

```
$for(author)$
author given: $author.given$
author family: $author.family$
$endfor$
```